# Isn't there any divisor $k$ of $n^4$ such that $n^2-n<k<n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I did some experiment with my Python script to find a number which could divide $n^4$ in this interval ($n^2-n$,  $n^2$).
I watched the form of prim factors of the numbers in this ($n^2-n$,  $n^2$) interval, but I hadn't was any idea for proofing it.
Can anyone to help with some start idea to proof that if $n^2-n < k < n^2$ then $k$ can't divide $n^4$.

Comment: $n$ doesn't divide $k$. Since $n<k$, there must be a prime number $p$ which divides $k$ but not $n$, thus also not $n^4$, so $k$ cannot divide $n^4$

Comment: @PinkPanther  Why does the fact that $n$ does not divide $k$ imply that there is a prime $p$ dividing $k$ but not $n$? After all, $6$ does not divide $3$.

Comment: @lulu you have to use the fact that $n<k$, then it should be very straight forward.

Comment: @PinkPanther  Could you write it out?  $12$ does not divide $18$ either...

Comment: @lulu you are right. I guess what I wanted to say is that there is a prime power which divides $k$ but not $n$, that is, there exists $p$ and $l$ such that $p^l$ divides $k$ but not $n$.I will write a complete answer in a moment.

Comment: @lulu forget about my comments, they don't make any sense.
I am very sorry about the confusion. I should have thought longer before commenting.

Comment: @PinkPanther In my Python experiments I always see that there is a new prime factor in $k$, which  wasn't in $n$, but I also can't explain it.

Comment: n=2 has a counterexample $n^2-n=n$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee how is that a counter example? if $n=2$ then $n^2- n < k < n$ means $2 < k < 2$ which is impossible.

Comment: okay I thought it included $n^2-n$ but apparently not an inclusive interval.

Comment: I don't have it but this would mean $1 - \frac 1n < \frac k{n^2} < 1$ interms of prime factorization that would mean $1-\frac 1{\prod p_i^{a_i}\prod q_i^{b_i}\prod r_i^{c_i}}< \frac {\prod q_i^{d_i-2b_i}}{\prod p_i^{2a_i - e_i}}< 1$ for $2b_i<d_i\le 4a_i$ and $e_i < 2a_i$.  This seems unlikely as the denominator $\prod p_i^{a_i}\prod q_i^{b_i}\prod r_i^{c_i}$ seems so much larger and "finer" than the denominator $\prod p_i^{2a_i - e_i}$.  But I haven't worked out the details (and its giving me a headache).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $0<i<n$ and suppose that $n^2-i$ divides $n^4$. Then,
$$
n^4=(n^2-i)(n^2+j)=n^4+(j-i)n^2-i\,j\implies i\,j=(j-i)n^2
$$
for some integer $j$. If $j\le i$, then
$$
n^4=(n^2-i)(n^2+j)\le(n^2-i)(n^2+i)=n^4-i^2.
$$
Thus, $j>i$. Since $i<n$, it follows that $j>(j-i)n\ge n$. Moreover
$$
n\le j=\frac{i\,n^2}{n^2-i}<\frac{i\,n^2}{n^2-n}=\frac{i\,n}{n-1}\implies i>n-1,
$$
a contradiction with the fact that $i<n$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer, but I can't see one step at this moment:
How can we now that $j>i$ ?. And this presumption is used in
$(j−i)n>n$ as I see.

Comment: $ij > 0$ and $n^2 > 0$ so if $ij = (j-i)n^2 > 0$ then $j-i > 0$.  ...(I suppose it should be points out that $i$ is positive (as $i = n^2 k; n^2 -n < k < n^2$. Ad that that $j > 0$ As if $k < n^2$ then $\frac {n^4}{k} > n^2$ so $n^2 + j = \frac {n^4}{k}$.)

Comment: My answer is along the same lines, and I had deleted it when I saw that, but then I noticed that you claimed that $(j-i)n\gt n$ when it is not clear why $j-i\gt1$.

Comment: @fleablood Why $i*j>0$ is ?

Comment: Why is $i*j > 0$.  Seriously?  Because $i > 0$ and $j > 0$.  And, as I said $i > 0$ because $n^2 > k$ so $i = n^2 -k > 0$ and $j > 0$ because $k < n^2 $ so $n^2 = \frac {n^4}{n^2} < \frac {n^4}k$.  So $j = \frac {n^4}k - n^2 > 0$.

Comment: @JuliánA Now I understood all steps and why was $j>i$ too .
$i*j=(j-i)*n^2$ implies that $j$ can't be element of  closed interval of $[0, i]$.
And $n^4=(n^2-i)*(n^2+j)$ implies that $n^2+j>n^2$, because $(n^2-i)<n^2$
so $j>0$ and thus$j>i$ can be only. Thanks again.

Comment: I am still not clear, from this answer, why $(j-i)n\gt n$, as is claimed; that is, why is $j-i\gt1$?

Comment: @robjohn If $j\le i$ then $$n^4=(n^2-i)(n^2+j)\le(n^2-i)(n^2+i)=n^4-i^2<n.$$ Thus, $i<j$. If $j=i+1$ then $$n^4=(n^2-i)(n^2+i+1)=n^4+n^2-i^2-i,$$ and $n^2=i^2+i$, impossible.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: In my opinion, this is not immediately obvious from the answer, and so should be included in the answer. Even the fact that "$n^2=i^2+i$ is impossible" should probably be justified in the answer.

Comment: @robjohn I have included the proof that $j>i$. It is not necessary to show that $j-i>1$. It is enough to change at two points $<$ by $\le$.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to the Question**

Let $k=n^2-a$. Since $n^2-a\mid n^4$ and
$$
\frac{n^4}{n^2-a}=n^2+a+\frac{a^2}{n^2-a}
$$
we must have $d=\frac{a^2}{n^2-a}\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, since $\color{#C00}{1\le a\le n-1}$ and $\frac{a^2}{n^2-a}$ is increasing in $a$,
$$
0\lt\overbrace{\ \frac1{n^2-1}\ }^{\large\color{#C00}{a=1}}\le d\le\overbrace{\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n^2-n+1}}^{\large\color{#C00}{a=n-1}}\lt1
$$
which is impossible because there is no integer between $0$ and $1$.

---

**Bounding the Greatest Factor of $\boldsymbol{n^4}$ less than $\boldsymbol{n^2}$**

**Case: $\boldsymbol{d=1}$**

Since $n^2=a^2+a$, we have $n-1\lt a\lt n$, which is impossible.

**Case: $\boldsymbol{d=2}$**

Since $n^2=\frac{a(a+2)}2$, $\sqrt2\,n-1\lt a\lt\sqrt2\,n$. In fact, $2n^2+1=(a+1)^2$. That means that
$$
\left(\frac{a+1}n\right)^2=2+\frac1{n^2}\lt\left(\sqrt2+\frac1{2n^2}\right)^2
$$
Which forces $\frac{a+1}n$ to be a continued fraction overestimate of $\sqrt2$ . This gives the first pairs $(n,a)$ to be
$$
\{(0,0),(2,2),(12,16),(70,98),(408,576),(2378,3362),(13860,19600)\}
$$
The recursion for $n_k$ is $n_k=6n_{k-1}-n_{k-2}$ and $a_k=\left\lfloor\sqrt2\,n\right\rfloor$.

In any case, we have

> The largest factor of $n^4$ less than $n^2$ must be less than $n^2-\sqrt2\,n+1$ and there are an infinite number of $n$ so that the largest factor of $n^4$ less than $n^2$ is greater than $n^2-\sqrt2\,n$.

Comment: Why $m-k>=1$ is ?

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi: I have extended the answer to cover that and to free up $k$.

Comment: I would also like to understand your derivation, but now I can see a few letters of error in it and then pleas correct it if you have the time. /: ($b-a=n^2/ab$) and what is role of $k$

Comment: I changed from $k$ and $m$ to $a$ and $b$ to avoid conflict with $k$ from the question. In the first sentence, it is stated that $k=n^2-a$. Since $n^4=n^4+(b-a)n^2-ab$, we have $(b-a)n^2=ab$. I fixed the typo.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi evidently the sharp result is that we can have a factor of $n^4$ as large as $n^2  - \lfloor n \sqrt 2 \rfloor \; , \;$ but no larger. This occurs with integers $x,y > 0,$ $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1,$ and then $n=2xy.$

Comment: @robjohn I have understood all your steps at this morning with a fresh head. Thank you too.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi: and I have (hopefully) simplified the answer a bit. I have also added sections showing the sharp result mentioned by Will Jagy.

Answer (score 2):

The best examples come from $n=2xy,$ where $x,y>0$ are integers and $x^2 - 2 y^2 = \pm 1 \; . \;$ In these cases we get a factor $m$ of $n^4$ near $n^2 - n \sqrt 2 \; . \; $ When $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1,$ we get $m = n^2 - 2 x^2.$ When $x^2 - 2 y^2 = -1,$ we get $m = n^2 - 4 y^2.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse
 n: 2 =  2  m:  2  n^2 - m:  2 =  2
 n: 3 =  3  m:  3  n^2 - m:  6 =  2 3
 n: 4 =  2^2  m:  8  n^2 - m:  8 =  2^3
 n: 6 =  2 3  m:  27  n^2 - m:  9 =  3^2
 n: 10 =  2 5  m:  80  n^2 - m:  20 =  2^2 5
 n: 12 =  2^2 3  m:  128  n^2 - m:  16 =  2^4
 n: 24 =  2^3 3  m:  512  n^2 - m:  64 =  2^6
 n: 30 =  2 3 5  m:  810  n^2 - m:  90 =  2 3^2 5
 n: 60 =  2^2 3 5  m:  3456  n^2 - m:  144 =  2^4 3^2
 n: 70 =  2 5 7  m:  4802  n^2 - m:  98 =  2 7^2
 n: 84 =  2^2 3 7  m:  6912  n^2 - m:  144 =  2^4 3^2
 n: 140 =  2^2 5 7  m:  19208  n^2 - m:  392 =  2^3 7^2
 n: 168 =  2^3 3 7  m:  27783  n^2 - m:  441 =  3^2 7^2
 n: 180 =  2^2 3^2 5  m:  32000  n^2 - m:  400 =  2^4 5^2
 n: 408 =  2^3 3 17  m:  165888  n^2 - m:  576 =  2^6 3^2
 n: 594 =  2 3^3 11  m:  351384  n^2 - m:  1452 =  2^2 3 11^2
 n: 816 =  2^4 3 17  m:  663552  n^2 - m:  2304 =  2^8 3^2
 n: 1170 =  2 3^2 5 13  m:  1366875  n^2 - m:  2025 =  3^4 5^2
 n: 2378 =  2 29 41  m:  5651522  n^2 - m:  3362 =  2 41^2
 n: 3230 =  2 5 17 19  m:  10425680  n^2 - m:  7220 =  2^2 5 19^2
 n: 4756 =  2^2 29 41  m:  22606088  n^2 - m:  13448 =  2^3 41^2
 n: 5880 =  2^3 3 5 7^2  m:  34560000  n^2 - m:  14400 =  2^6 3^2 5^2
 n: 13860 =  2^2 3^2 5 7 11  m:  192080000  n^2 - m:  19600 =  2^4 5^2 7^2
 n: 16296 =  2^3 3 7 97  m:  265531392  n^2 - m:  28224 =  2^6 3^2 7^2
 n: 27720 =  2^3 3^2 5 7 11  m:  768320000  n^2 - m:  78400 =  2^6 5^2 7^2
 n: 42672 =  2^4 3 7 127  m:  1820786688  n^2 - m:  112896 =  2^8 3^2 7^2
 n: 57960 =  2^3 3^2 5 7 23  m:  3359232000  n^2 - m:  129600 =  2^6 3^4 5^2
 n: 58206 =  2 3 89 109  m:  3387795864  n^2 - m:  142572 =  2^2 3 109^2
 n: 80782 =  2 13^2 239  m:  6525617282  n^2 - m:  114242 =  2 239^2
```

Comment: (+1) for the inspiration to prove the maximum.